# How to get the effect of putting a DIV in a TEXTAREA?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

From what I've searched, it's not possible to use a div tag inside textarea. Can anyone suggest an alternative method for what I'm trying to achieve?

I want the template selected in the drop down box to load inside the text box.

Controlpanel.php

```
<h2><u>Edit</u></h2>
<form action="ajax/name.php" name="edit_template_form" id="edit_template_form" method="post">
<select name="edit" id='edit_template_name'>

    <?php foreach($res as $row){
    print "<option value=".$row['template_name']." >".$row['template_name']."</option>";
    } ?>

</select><br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="25" name="template_edit" id="template_edit"><div id="edit_template"></div></textarea><br/>
<button type="button" name="edit_submit" id="edit_submit">Submit</button></form>
<div id="edit_data"></div>
```

testprocess.js

```
$('#edit_submit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var edit_template = $('#template_edit').val();
    var edit_name = $('#edit_template_name').val();
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {edit_name: edit_name, edit_template: edit_template}, function(data) {
        $('div#edit_template').text(data);
   });      
   location.reload(true);
});
```

name.php

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_template'])) {
    $template_edit = $db->escape($_POST['edit_template']);
    $template_name = $db->escape($_POST['edit_name']);
    $user = $db->escape($user);

    $db->update('templates', array('template_description' => $template_edit), 'template_name="'.$template_name.'" AND userID="'.$user.'"');

    echo $_POST['edit_template'];
}
```

Comment: Err… just use the value of the textbox instead of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$('div#edit_template').text(data);
```

with this:

```
$('textarea#template_edit').val(data);
```